# How to Add NewLine to RichTextBox from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, richtextbox, viewmodel

I am trying to add a paragraph to a richtextbox from my viewmodel but i keep failing. My viewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the value of the richtextbox inside the viewModel is a string. For example:

```
private string richBox;

public string RichBox
{
     get { return richBox; }
     set { richBox = value; Changed("RichBox"); }
}
```

etc.

When i try to add the paragraph inside `public myViewModel()` like:

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p1.Inlines.Add(new Run("..........."+"\n" + "-----------"));
doc.Blocks.Add(p);
this.richBox = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd).Text;
```

it fails. Even when i add a new paragraph `p2` as `p2.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());`, also fails.

Instead of getting:

```
..........

----------
```

I get: `..........----------`

Everything i tried seems to fail.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: everything fails ? saying what ?

Comment: you are right @Muds. i forgot that part. I will add it to the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you just need a new line you can use "\line"

Append this to your Text

```
"\\line"
```

Comment: `p1.Inlines.Add(new Run("..........." + "\u2028" + "----------"));` shows `..........?----------` inside the richtextbox.

Comment: although its same but try "\line" instead

Comment: `\line` gives me an error. `Unrecognized escape sequence`

Comment: "\\line" to escape it

Comment: wow. that actually works!!!! add it as an answer so i can select it. Thanks @Muds